# Looking for S#arp Architecture usage without ASP.net MVC issues or gotchas

Tags: c#, orm, repository-pattern, s#arp-architecture

I am exploring technologies and libraries before I get started on a new project.  One that has really caught my eye is the S#arp Architecture library for ASP.net MVC.  However, I have already decide that the bulk of my web application will use Visual Web GUI as the front end, leaving only a small separate customer facing web component that will be developed in ASP.net MVC.  Bearing this in mind, based on the experiences of those of you who have a good familiarity with S#harp Architecture, or may have attempted a similar solution using S#harp, are there any issues or gotchas I should be aware of before I begin? I have also had a look at Castle Active Record, and Fluent NHibernate usage as possible options, but find myself leaning towards S#arp.

My most major goal in choosing a library are to get my data access set up using the repository pattern as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your main goal is to flesh out a persistence layer quickly then S#arp Architecture is a bit overload IMO. S#arp makes use of Fluent NHibernate so I'd just go with that. [FNH's auto mapping conventions](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Auto_mapping) should slice a big chunk off your dev time.

I wouldn't say S#arp is a library. It's more of a boilerplate for Domain Driven Design. You should be familiar with Dependency Injection (aka Inversion of Control), Test Driven Development, Rhino Mocks, and NHibernate before you start looking at S#arp (because those are the concepts and technologies used in it). Otherwise the learning curve will be quite steep.

Comment: I could not agree more with what Matt said. For what you are wanting, S# most likely is too much, kind of like using a sledgehammer to drive a staple.

Comment: My hope was that with s#harp I wouldn't have to learn fluent nhibernate best practices myself, and could benefit from their integrations with log4net and Windsor without having to deep dive into them up front, but instead focus at first on my problem domain, and then organically pick up the finer points of using these other systems in a large scale application.  But it appears that is not a very realistic goal.  So I'm off to my playground repository to tinker with these tools individually until I can figure out how best to utilize them for my solution.

Comment: I highly recommend fluent nhibernate. It's really not that much of a learning curve and pays high dividends. If you want to get up to speed with nhibernate then check out http://www.summerofnhibernate.com/ these excellent screen casts from Stephen A. Bohlen will quickly get you started.

Answer (score 0):

We have implemented a ASP.NET standard project using the S#harp framework without any problems. I would strongly recommend you start coding from the Services layer and leave no logic in your codebehind aspx files. We do also make big efforts to avoid having logic in Controllers as we saw them as codebehinds files and try to put all the system logic in the services.

Just make sure you plug all necesarry in your **global asax file** and you should have no problem at all. If you are using NHibernate, Fluent, Service Injection and DDD is really easy to make it work with old asp.net web application.